# Existence of a specific function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am supposed to construct a function, which is defined on interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, as well as $f(a)=f(b)$ and $$f{}'(x)\neq 0$$ for each $x$, which belongs to $(a,b)$.

I was thinking about Rolle's theorem and thought, that this is not possible, but, Rolle's theorem does not satisfy it.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: For each x, which does not belong to (a,b)? Don't you mean which does belong?

Comment: yes, I edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be:

$f(x)=x$ , for $x\in(a,b)$

$f(a)=f(b)=73$

$f'(x)=1$ for all $x\in(a,b)$

Comment: Is there concrete reason, why f(a)=f(b)=73?

Comment: No it could be any other number. I just happen to like 73 :)

Comment: okay, thank you